# Extend Thread to test proper termination with join?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Java Concurrency In Practice, 12.1.2. Testing Blocking Operations:

```
void testTakeBlocksWhenEmpty() {
 final BoundedBuffer<Integer> bb = new BoundedBuffer<Integer>(10);
 Thread taker = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
   try {
    int unused = bb.take();
    fail(); // if we get here, it’s an error
   } catch (InterruptedException success) { }
  }
 };
 try {
  taker.start();
  Thread.sleep(LOCKUP_DETECT_TIMEOUT);
  taker.interrupt();
  taker.join(LOCKUP_DETECT_TIMEOUT);
  assertFalse(taker.isAlive());
 } catch (Exception unexpected) {
  fail();
 }
}
```

> This is one of the few cases in which it is appropriate to subclass
>   Thread explicitly instead of using a Runnable in a pool: in order to
>   test proper termination with join. The same approach can be used to
>   test that the taker thread unblocks after an element is placed in the
>   queue by the main thread.

But I don't see how extending Thread helps with testing that. For me it seems that the same test could be done with passing `Runnable` to `Thread`. Can somebody explain that?

Comment: Note: the `fail()` won't cause the test to fail. It will print an error, but the test will pass.  BTW If you don't catch a thrown `Exception` in a test it fails anyway, but you get to see why rather than a generic `AssertionError`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, I noticed this code is not perfect and just to make sure we're on the same page, this is code from the book, not mine. ; )

Comment: The quote says, "...instead of using a Runnable _in a pool_."  Maybe it's talking about the appropriateness of directly creating a `Thread` instance instead of letting a thread pool object or a factory object do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is one of the few cases in which it is appropriate to subclass
>   Thread explicitly instead of using a Runnable in a pool: **in order to
>   test proper termination with join.**

In other words that approach lets you a chance to interrupt the test thread and join it to make sure it has been terminated properly. You can't handle threads in that way if you use, for example - `ThreadPoolExecutor` class.

Also, it is OK to create a new thread, initiating it with Runnable, like `Thread taker = new Thread(() -> {...});`. Remember that the book was written about 8 years ago, and creating `Runnable` instead of subclass of `Thread` would make that example a bit longer.